# Rewrite case statement to if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have an ActiveRecord query like this. And this code works without problem.

```
order(<<-SQL)
  CASE WHEN MAX(disclosures.filed_at) > MAX(short_positions.published_on)
  THEN MAX(disclosures.filed_at)
  ELSE MAX(short_positions.published_on)
  END
SQL
```

And I thought it would be more simple if I write it with if statement.

```
order(<<-SQL)
  IF (MAX(disclosures.filed_at) > MAX(short_positions.published_on))
  THEN MAX(disclosures.filed_at)
  ELSE MAX(short_positions.published_on)
  END IF
SQL
```

But it failed with an error:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "MAX" LINE 1: ... 1) GROUP BY companies.id ORDER BY IF MAX(disclo.
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### Whole SQL

```
"SELECT companies.* FROM \"companies\" INNER JOIN \"stocks\" ON \"stocks\".\"company_id\" = \"companies\".\"id\" INNER JOIN \"disclosures\" ON \"disclosures\".\"company_id\" = \"companies\".\"id\" INNER JOIN \"short_positions\" ON \"short_positions\".\"company_id\" = \"companies\".\"id\" WHERE (stocks.user_id = 1) GROUP BY companies.id  ORDER BY            IF MAX(disclosures.filed_at) > MAX(short_positions.published_on)\n           THEN MAX(disclosures.filed_at)\n           ELSE MAX(short_positions.published_on)\n           END IF\n"
```

Comment: There is no `IF` statement in the plain SQL.

Answer (score 2):

There should be `THEN` keyword present..

```
order(<<-SQL)
  IF (MAX(disclosures.filed_at) > MAX(short_positions.published_on)) THEN
    MAX(disclosures.filed_at)
  ELSE
    MAX(short_positions.published_on)
  END IF
SQL
```

[PostgreSQL Control Structures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)

Comment: Thanks, but there is still an error. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Is that the whole sql which you have posted or just a snippet?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the portion was enough. I put whole SQL in my question.

Comment: I couldn't find any good example of `if..else..` in an `order by` clause, every one suggests using `Case` statements. Probable reason for your error is that the conditionals should return `select statements` which is to be written explicitly for `if..else..` whereas `Case` handles it on his own.

Comment: Honestly saying my understanding is quite vaguely, I'll learn again SQL statements from basic. Thanks!